# display popup box automatically after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a time counter script and at the end of this script i wish to run a code through ajax, and its result should appear in the popup box.
here is my code

```
var ticker = function() {
  counter--;
  var t = (counter / 60) | 0; // it is round off
  digits.eq(0).text(t);
  t = ((counter % 60) / 10) | 0;
  digits.eq(2).text(t);
  t = (counter % 60) % 10;
  digits.eq(3).text(t);
  if (!counter) {
    clearInterval(timer);
   // alert('Time out !');


        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
             url:'timewalkaway.php',
             dataType: 'json',
            data:{txt:txtbox,hidden:hiddenTxt},
            cache:false,
            success: function(returndataaa){

                console.log(returndataaa)


                if (returndataaa[2] == 'No deal') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("Sorry! We both tried hard, but could not reach a deal. You can buy on our last offer deal.");
                $('#proddisplay').load('reply1.php');

                if (returndataaa[2] == 'priority_one') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("You made us an offer we cannot refuse. Click Buy Now We do not offer this price to everyone");
                $('#proddisplay').load('reply2.php');

                if (returndataaa[2] == 'priority_two') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("This offer is slightly low, we can give this product if you pay us through Cash On delivery!!");  
                $('#proddisplay').load('reply3.php');

                if (returndataaa[2] == 'priority_two1') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("This offer is slightly low, we can give this product if you pay us through Cash On delivery!!");  
                $(proddisplay).load('reply3.php');


                if (returndataaa[2] == 'priority_three1') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("Hey! this is a low offer, we can accept this offer if you agree to write a review for this product");
                $('#proddisplay').load('reply4.php');

                if (returndataaa[2] == 'priority_three2') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("Hey! this is a low offer we can accept this offer if you can share about us on facebook using the link after checkout, we wil give the amt after the checkout.");
                $('#proddisplay').load('reply5.php');

                if (returndataaa[2] == 'priority_four1') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("A low offer indeed! If you write us a product review and give us cash on delivery we can take this offer");
                $('#proddisplay').load('reply6.php');

                if (returndataaa[2] == 'priority_four2') 
                //$('#proddisplay').text("A low offer indeed! If you share this on facebook and give cash on delivery we can take this offer"); 
                $('#proddisplay').load('reply7.php');

            }

        });

   resetView();
  }
};
```

I checked in console i am getting result in `console.log(returndataaa)` i want to make a div with id proddisplay inside a popup box to display data, but i am not able to understand how should i display popup box automatically within this script and display the result in it

Comment: Show the full code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `load()` which gets called when the load completes. You can show your pop-up then.

```
$('#proddisplay').load('reply1.php', function( response, status, xhr ) {
  // Create and show your pop-up here.
  console.log(returndataaa);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use <kbd>**[`jquery-ui dialog`.](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)**</kbd> Just add an element like one below:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
```

And I suggest you to use `switch` case  instead of `if` in this scenario and use <kbd>**[`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)**</kbd> and <kbd>**[`.done`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)**</kbd> to load `dialog` when `php` load is done:

```
var isloadSuccess=true; //Just to display proper load data in dialog
$.when(
$.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:'timewalkaway.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         data:{txt:txtbox,hidden:hiddenTxt},
         cache:false,
         success: function(returndataaa){
                switch(returndataa[2])
                { 
                     case 'No deal':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply1.php');
                          break;
                     case 'priority_one':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply2.php');
                           break;
                     case 'priority_two':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply3.php');
                          break;
                     case 'priority_two1':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply3.php');
                          break;
                     case 'priority_three1':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply4.php');
                          break;
                     case 'priority_three2':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply5.php');
                          break;
                     case 'priority_four1':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply6.php');
                          break;
                     case 'priority_four2':
                          $('#proddisplay').load('reply7.php');
                          break;
                     default:
                          isloadSuccess=false;
                          break;
                 }
          }
})).done(function(){
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); //Keep it open and in case load is unsuccess then display error message
    $(".ui-dialog-content").empty();

    if(isloadSuccess) //check php has been loaded, it will be false only in default case when php hasn't been loaded
          $(".ui-dialog-content").append($('#proddisplay'));//append it to dialog's body
    else
          $(".ui-dialog-content").append("<p>Something went wrong</p>")
});
```

Comment: it got me the result but the popup box did not get displayed

Comment: You need to add `jquery-ui.js` into your page @st001

Comment: Can you just edit the question and post your complete `html`? Try checking your console once for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery ui dialog:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#proddisplay").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  alert('Showing popup in next 2 seconds...');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#proddisplay").dialog("open");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="proddisplay" title="Product dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Also you could reduce your existing code and get rid of those if...else. Make a global object as follows:

```
var pages = {
  'No deal' : 'reply1.php',
  'priority_one' : 'reply2.php',
  'priority_two' : 'reply3.php',
  'priority_two1' : 'reply3.php',
  'priority_three1' : 'reply4.php',
  'priority_four1' : 'reply6.php',
  'priority_four2' : 'reply7.php'
};
```

Update you success block as follows:

```
success: function(returndataaa){
    $('#proddisplay').load(pages[returndataaa[2]]);
    $("#proddisplay").dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: i tried ur code but still the popup is not getting displayed

Comment: Kindly check whether the ajax call status fail/pass from the browser's network panel under `XHR` tab.

Answer (score 0):

To display the result in popup, first, initialize the dialog window as.

```
$("#proddisplay").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Details",
    buttons: {
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Then in ajax success,

```
success: function(returndataaa){
    $('#proddisplay').load('reply1.php'); // change the page name accordingly
    $("#proddisplay").dialog("open");
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Show-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-after-AJAX-Call-Success.aspx) post for more details.